# Access __NSDictionaryI data

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

Im saving a dictionary into NSUserDefaults with the below code:

```
let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(self.markerArray)
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(data, forKey: "pins")
```

To access this data I use

```
let outData = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dataForKey("pins")
let dict = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(outData!)
```

when printing **dict** I get what I want: a full dictionary of data (sample):

> ```
> 79 =     {
>     address = "Arizona, USA";
>     category = nature;
>     id = 135;
>     lang = "-112.113";
>     lat = "36.107";
>     name = "Grand Canyon National Park";
>     placeId = ChIJFU2bda4SM4cRKSCRyb6pOB8;
>     type = "point_of_interest";
> };
> ```

Now when I want to access a specific entry, all I get is **nil**

```
print(dict!["79"]!["name"]!)
```

The unarchived dictionary is of type **__NSDictionaryI** if that helps.
Running the below code also prints **nil**

```
print("dict[79] is of type: \(dict!["79"]!.dynamicType)")
```

Comment: Saving a dictionary from a variable name marker**Array** is pretty confusing.

Comment: Since you already have `NSKeyedArchiver` and data just save it in a file in the Documents directory. That is a much better solution.

`NSUserDefaults` really is not designed to be a datastore, the name says a lot: User Defaults.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you have a type problem. Why would `79` have to be a string? I guess it's just a number (`NSNumber`).

See the following example:

```
let dict: NSDictionary = [
    79: "test 1",
   "79": "test 2"
]

print(dict[79]) // prints "test 1"
print(dict["79"]) // prints "test 2"
```

Comment: @ArEsiiX Have you tried to actually inspect the type of the key? e.g. using `print(dict.allKeys.map({$0.description + " \($0.dynamicType)"}))`?